# java trouble reading line from file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

My code is not reading the line from file. But I'm not sure why. Beginner level Java, any input is helpful.

Thanks.

```
public class ReverseWords {

public static void main(String [] args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter File Name: ");
    String fileName = in.nextLine();
    File f = new File(fileName);
    try {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(f);
                    int n = input.nextInt();  
        String line = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
            String [] words = line.split(" ");

            for(int i=0; i<words.length; i++){
                System.out.println(words[i]);

            }


             } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }

}
```

Comment: How does content of your file looks like? I suspect that problem is that `nextInt()` is not reading line till the end (it leaves new line mark), so first `nextLine()` is returning empty String (since it was the only thing Scanner could find before new line mark) and the second nextLine() will read correct data.

Comment: I think the issue lies with reading the int. Try removing the line `int in = input.nextInt();`

Comment: Could you show the contents of your file ?

Comment: @RahulBobhate...5
this is a test
foobar
all your base
class
pony along

Comment: all on seperate lines tho

Answer (score 1):

With no file contents I can only make a guess.

`nextInt()` doesn't change the line counter in `Scanner`, so `nextLine()` call will return the rest of the line you're currently at.
That's probably not what you want and it's the reason why no lines are read.

To avoid that you could explicitly change line counter by doing an extra `nextLine()` call after your `nextInt()`:

```
int n = input.nextInt(); 
input.nextLine();
String line = input.nextLine();
```

From [Scanner.nextLine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) API doc:

> This method returns the rest of the current line, excluding any line
>   separator at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you got filenotfound exception.

you have to specify absolute path as input.

```
drive:/sample/input.txt
```

first try reading a source file from directly

```
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("drive:/dir/file"));
```

or you can place the file where your project exists. [The folder is named as the project name]
In this case you can **simply specify "file.extesion"** as input to read from that file.

But if the file exists: (can check with new File(filename.ext).exists()) then check whether there is input to read

for reading entire file or further lines you should put that in loop (you actually read only one line)

```
while(sc.hasnextLine())
{
 line=sc.nextLine()    //check it first and then process
 //process this line for words
```

}

Comment: well its reading the first line of the file, hwich is an int, but not the second line